# StackOverflow API, is there any progress in this area?

Tags: feature-request, api

StackOverflow API, is there any progress in this area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/.

Answer (score 0):

There are already several implementations (not complete of course) for Python, .NET, Ruby, .NET CF, PHP, and more underway.

Request a beta invite, they will get you in rather quickly.